# Adding a file to Pipedrive via API; What am I missing?? ( PHP )

Tags: php

Hoping you can help!

Trying to add a file via the /files endpoint; very simple piece of code but just won't work.
$URL contains the correct endpoint and api token; $DLFile has the local path for the file I want to upload.

Seems like the "file" key isn't recognised but that makes no sense for the /files endpoint as when I remove it from the request it says there's no input.

```
$PIPEDRIVE = array('file'=>'$DLFILE','deal_id'=>154);
$curl = curl_init($URL);
$Headers = [
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
'Cache-Control: no-cache'
];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $Headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PIPEDRIVE);
 
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $output;
```

And this is the response

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "Invalid input: file - This field was not expected.",
    "error_info": "Please check developers.pipedrive.com for more information about Pipedrive API.",
    "data": null,
    "additional_data": null
}
```

Comment: _“$DLFile has the local path for the file I want to upload”_ - only you are not doing any actual file upload, you are just sending this path as a _text_ value. For an example of how it is actually done, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php

Comment: Correction, you are not even sending the actual path, you are sending the variable _name_ as text. (Difference between single and double quotes.)

Comment: Apologies; I'd taken the variable out for testing and put it back in for this example so people wouldn't advise something like "You're sending it out as blank and not the file path" but accidently left the single quotes in.

Comment: @CBroe it was the curl_file_create I was missing; got the stupid feels going now!; thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

“$DLFile has the local path for the file I want to upload” - only you are not doing any actual file upload, you are just sending this path as a text value. For an example of how it is actually done, see php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php – CBroe

curl_file_create is what was missing